# Google Analytics limits definitions

Tags: google-analytics

I'm writing a plugin that creates quite some events for GA. I'd like to check the meaning of definitions used on pages like https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/limits-quotas and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas.

These are some of the limits and quotas

- 10 million hits per month per property
- 50,000 requests per project per day
- 500 hits per session
- 200,000 hits per visitor per day

I'd like to know what is meant by:

- hit
- property
- request
- project
- session

Also, if a household shares the same IP address, they will be  one visitor, right?

About the 50,000 requests. Would this assumption be right?

Total requests = total pageviews (=hits?) + total events
So if there are 4200 pageviews and 46000 events, I have already reached the 50,000 requests?

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html. And "requests" is about API usage, not data collection.

Comment: Very clever. Didn't think of it. The requests part is still not clear to me. Am I right when I say I don't need to worry about the 50,000 requests, but more about the 500 hits per session?

Comment: to be clear... is your plugin using the actual google API or is it custom coding that involves normal tracking code (`_gaq()` or `ga()` calls). Because those are 2 different things with 2 different limits

Comment: if you are unsure, then please explain what your plugin actually does

Comment: It's a modification of Brian Cray's code http://briancray.com/posts/time-on-site-bounce-rate-get-the-real-numbers-in-google-analytics. I'm not using a Google API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, since you clarified that your plugin is for normal GA tracking (urchin.js or ga.js or analytics.js) and not the GA API, some of those limits aren't applicable.  So here are the ones that are applicable to your plugin and some extra info about them:

**Hit** - 500 hits per session. This is any `_trackPageview` or `_trackEvent` request made.  More specifically, it's any request made that is not ecommerce, though those 2 methods are the only currently official methods that actually make a request that aren't ecommerce.

One thing to note is that this limit is on a *per visit(or)* basis, not *all* visit(or)s as a whole. So for example, if you have 2 visitors on your site, the "500 hits per session" applies to *each* visitor separately. Each one has their own 500 hits per session limit.

The 2nd thing to understand is what a **[Session](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en#visits_vs_visitors)** actually is.  A session is a minimum of 30 minutes long, but will not end until a visitor is inactive for at least 30 minutes. "Inactive" means, more than 30 minutes has passed since the last hit to GA that is associated to that visitor.

*If you are using Universal Analytics* (analytcs.js) then there's also a 200k hits per visitor per day limit, though you generally don't need to worry about this unless you are writing code that manually forces a new session (because if you aren't doing that, by default you would hit the per session limit long before the per visitor per day limit. minimum default 30m session == 48 sessions in a day * 500 = 24k hits).

Final and potentially most important thing to note is that as mentioned, `_trackEvent` calls are included in determining limits.  So if your plugin is doing a lot of event tracking, you should try and minimize it as much as possible or really ask yourself how actionable that data is to begin with.  I've had clients ask me to implement things like trigger an event whenever a visitor hovers their mouse over form fields or images. I've even had clients as me to have an event trigger with mouse x,y positions whenever the mouse moves, or scrollbar positions whenever scrollbars are scrolled. Those visitor actions fire off an obscene amount of events that will very quickly put the visitor over the GA limit, and I have yet to hear any compelling reason to actually track this that has actually increased someone's ROI.

**Property** - This is one of the levels of GA's [account structure](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en).  The first thing to understand is this is the "global" or aggregated or "upper" limit imposed. For example, if you average visitor only produces 100 hits per session, you can still reach this upper limit by sheer number of visitors going to your site.

One important thing to note is that this limit is at the *property* level. A property can have multiple *views*, so this upper limit is across all views of the property combined. For example, one common setup is to have a single root domain as a property, e.g. "mysite.com" and then let's say you have several subdomains, e.g. "www" and "store" etc.. and you want to see these numbers separately.  One way to do this is to have a separate view for each subdomain.  Then lets say you want to also have a way to see all the data rolled up, so you make another "rollup" view.

IOW views are a way to separate sections or subdomains of your site, or one for multiple domains, etc.. it just depends on how you wanna organize things.  But the point is that if you do have something complex like this going on, one view can affect another view's data because of this upper limit. For example if you have a view for "www.mysite.com" for general traffic, and "store.mysite.com" for your ecommerce stuff, and  "rollup" view for combined traffic, and if generally have an extremely high level of general traffic, you may reach the limit and not get data for your more important store traffic (since that's the one that presumably makes you the money).  Note that this would only affect pageview/event traffic. [ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce) tracking will *always* be tracked, even if you go over hit limits.

**Request** and **Project** are not relevant to you because those are definitions for the non-collection APIs (e.g. the config or reporting APIs).

Comment: Clear! Kept me thinking, I have to reduce the number of hits per session. I don't want to reduce the session time, because that changes the pageview stats too much. People will go nuts when they see their number of pageviews go up. Thinking of limiting the tracking time with JS. Thanks for answering my underlying question.

Comment: Is there a way to monitor those limits? How can I tell if in certain cases I exceed those limits?

Comment: This answer is outdated. Ecommerce hits are counted towards the limit of 500 hits per session. Updated quotas: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of limits - one refer to data collection, i.e. the stuff you want to store inside Google Analytics. That's where the hit limits come in an as per my comment the definitions are in the [Google Terms of service](http://google.com/analytics/terms/us.html).

The other kind refers to API usage, i.e. when you want to pull stored data out of Google Analytics. To do so you send http requests in a specified format to Google Analytics and your are allowed as a default 50 000 of those requests per day.

So hit limits are about data going into Analytics, request limits are about data coming out of it.